# Could a Warlock use the One with Shadows eldritch invocation to remain invisible during a long rest/sleep?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, invisibility, rests, eldritch-invocations

The warlock's One with Shadows [eldritch invocation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations) presents an interesting opportunity: it gives you invisibility without requiring concentration. Specifically (PHB, p. 111):

> ### One with Shadows
>
> *Prerequisite: 5th level*
>
> When you are in an area of dim light or darkness, you can use your
> action to become invisible until you move or take an action or a
> reaction.

Unlike the [*invisibility*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/invisibility) spell, this would not necessarily end if the warlock became unconscious. However, the wording that says that this spell ends if you "move or take an action or a reaction" seems to imply that this invisibility is usually intended to last for a very short duration.

But it occurred to me that outside of combat, people often don't do much that technically requires an action, especially if they are at rest. And at [other times](https://www.sageadvice.eu/2016/08/02/would-standing-up-from-prone-trigger-the-effects-of-booming-blade/), it has been [indicated](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/659436991956799488?lang=en)  that "moving" (for the purpose of magical triggers) refers to moving in the sense of spending movement to change your location on a 2D grid (not becoming prone, or standing up from prone).

So I was wondering: could a warlock use an action to Hide<sup>1</sup>, then **use the One with Shadows invocation to become invisible, then simply lie down and go to sleep for 8 hours (for a long rest), while remaining invisible** (and likely hidden)?

Put another way: is there some action, reaction, or move required during a long rest?

---

<sup>1</sup>  <sub>I included the part about Hiding because according to the rules as written, an unhidden creature that is invisible is still apparent to creatures around it (it can't be seen, but they know where it is). So I wanted to include the hiding part to avoid that argument. And I did so beforehand, because using the Hide action while invisible would break the invisibility.</sub>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### This should work, if it's the last thing you do before going to sleep.

Outside of combat, we typically don't *account* for actions, but this invocation would require keeping track of whether you do something that would be an action. For example, you can eat during a rest, but that would use an action if done in combat, so it would break the invisibility (because the magic doesn't care whether you *call* it an action).

However, if the warlock goes into an enclosed, dark space, lies down, invokes the magic, and then goes to sleep, yeah, they can be invisible until waking up.

### A caveat about doing this during a *short* rest

(not actually the question, but it seems relevant)

The short rest rules mention "tending to wounds" as a possible activity, and allow regaining hit points by spending Hit Dice, but don't actually *say* that you have to tend to your wounds to regain hit points. I would argue that the rules imply that wound care is an *expected* part of resting, and if you insist on spending the entire rest invisible instead of caring for your wounds, you can't spend Hit Dice. But depending on how your table treats the rules, and on how you interpret hit points, this could go either way.

Comment: Are you implying that you need to tend to wounds in order to regain hit points from a **long** rest? You make a good point about short rests, but the question was specifically about long rests.

Comment: Oddly, the long rest rules don't mention wound care at all. They also don't involve spending Hit Dice, so there's an implication that you don't have to do any work to regain hit points during a long rest; it just happens. It's still very unclear what exactly it means to spend Hit Dice, but whatever it is, it's not as effective as simply sleeping off the fatigue.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's limited to light conditions, then as long as you don't move, you can keep invisibility outside of combat actions.  It's not the Invisibility spell, you gain the invisible condition.

A long rest that didn't require moving would not affect the invisibility.  As long as you remain in low light and do not move, this condition could continue indefinitely.

Comment: Can you quote the relevant parts of the links you provided? Also I'm not sure how the concentration applies to the question.

Comment: They are tweets so they copy very poorly, and I don't think a screen grab meets copyright requirements.  It looks like this:  Can I start a short rest while keeping concentration on a spell like Hex?
SEPTEMBER 20, 2014ZOLTAR

Igor Ruffinengo
@ IgorRuffinengo
 · Sep 19, 2014
@ mikemearls Howdy, Mike! Just one question: can I start a short rest while keeping concentration on a spell like Hex? Thank you!


Mike Mearls
@ mikemearls
@ IgorRuffinengo as long as you don't sleep

Comment: I'm still unsure how the concentration applies to the question.

Comment: Concentration because another answer references it.  I can't comment on other posts.

Comment: All of this information is accurate, but I’m not sure why you mentioned short rests here, as the question is concerned with long rests.

Comment: @ScottDunnington: The only other answer on this question doesn't reference concentration at all... Regardless, your answer should stand alone as an answer to the question, not include unexplained sidebars that you're unable to post elsewhere.